# Is there any noncontinuous function f(x), such that the absolute value of f(x) is continuous?

Tags: continuity, absolute-value

I am trying to find such a function or a proof, which shows that there is no such function in general.
I know, that the other direction of this statement is true. (I prooved it using only the definiton). But here I have no idea, how to show it.
Thank you

Comment: Can you think of a non-continuous function such that $|f(x)| = 1$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Such functions do exist. Can you find one that takes one value on the rational numbers and a different value on the irrational numbers?